# Will code from Matlab R2012b work in Matlab R2013a environment?

Tags: matlab

Will code from Matlab R2012b work in Matlab R2013a environment?

I am not sure if I should switch from Matlab R2012b to Matlab R2013a?
I heard there are nice new features, but my major concern is whether my
code from 2012b will work with 2013a.

Please let me know if you have some major warnings about this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *very* rare for a new version to be incompatible with code of previous versions (unless you upgrade from dinosaur versions).

Comment: IIRC there are a number of functions which went from being deprecated to being unsupported in this release, so a more specific look would be appropriate for this question.

Comment: @Ansari I think that even if some fnctions have changed you can use them, while a warning message will appear telling you to change the function.

Comment: Deprecated functions in the previous release would have been spouting warnings already, so they should not have gone unnoticed.

Answer (score 2):

There's a brief list of changes [here](http://www.dynare.org/DynareWiki/MatlabVersionsCompatibility#MATLAB_8.1_.28R2013a.29). This includes several set theory functions whose behavior has changed, and a few less commonly used things that have been removed.